# How to output a TIF with only 3 samples/pixel

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I've been able to create a Topo from Canada's CanVec data. But after I 'Export as Image' and save my map to a TIF, I try importing it into Memory Map 6 and it says that it can't import the file because it has more than 3 samples/pixel.

After reading [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_(graphics)) I wonder if this could be a color type issue (RGB or PCT)? Is there to change how many samples/pixel there is?

Answer (score 1):

Export/Save Map as Image adds an Alpha channel so you get a 4 band RGBA output. Use the "Convert map to raster" Processing tool instead and you can output a 3 band RGB image.